# AEM adding infinite height on element in Editor mode

Tags: css, aem

We are using HTML Banner component while creating a webpage in AEM.
The Banner component having **height: 100vh** CSS property to cover the entire height of view port.
But while authoring in edit mode in AEM, the height of page is increasing infinity. So it is become a tedious task to author the page. AEM is adding height on several elements in edit mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is "Parsys"

When you add the component with a height of vh, It will try to occupy the full screen and AEM will try to add "Parsys" at the bottom. Now, vh will try to occupy the space of that Parsys has taken. So, again the parsys will go down, and again the vh will occupy the space. This is an infinity process.

We need to restrict JS

Answer (score 0):

You can add a workaround for your problem by adding an additional JavaScript that only exists on your author instance and run on the editor page. You have to create a client library somewhere in your project and add "[cq.authoring.editor]" to its categories property. This will make sure that your code runs on your editor page.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jcr:root xmlns:cq="http://www.day.com/jcr/cq/1.0" xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0"
    jcr:primaryType="cq:ClientLibraryFolder"
    categories="[cq.authoring.editor]"/>
```

For the JavaScript, you could add something like this,

`//bannerHeightAuthor.js`

```
$(() => {
    // get the content frame iframe's document object 
    let contentFrame = $('#ContentFrame').get(0).contentWindow.document
    // get the screen height
    let height = window.outerHeight

    $(contentFrame).find('.<banner_class>').each((_, banner) => {
        $(banner).css('height', height)
    })
})
```

inside your client library add js.txt file, and add the following code

```
bannerHeightAuthor.js
```

Answer (score 0):

In one of my components, I worked around this issue by reading the wcmmode, which lets me know if I am in author or publish mode. Once I know it is publish mode, I added a class and set the height. If it is author, the class doesn't exist and height will not be set.